Cannot convert type of ‘Color’ to expected argument of type ‘Binding<Color>’ error
I am unsure how I’m supposed to resolve this error.
I have a custom button style that I apply to each instance of a ForEach loop.
The error occurs in the bold part of the buttonStyle declaration below
This error comes up when I pass in the borderColor to the custom struct.
Here are snippets of code that hopefully paint enough of a picture.
    @State private var borderColor = Color.black


                ForEach(topArray, id: \.self) { topLetter in
                    Button(action: {
                        print("Top number keys")
                    }){
                        Text(topLetter)
                    }
#                     .buttonStyle(CustomButtonStyle(keyLabel: topLetter, newLetter: $newLetter, **borderColor: Color.black)**)

                }


Here is the custom buttonStyle:
struct CustomButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
        let keyLabel: String
        @Binding var newLetter : String 
        @Binding var borderColor: Color
        
        func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            configuration.label
                .padding()
                .border(borderColor)
                .onTapGesture {
                    // Change border color if label matches userPrompt
                    if keyLabel == newLetter {
                        borderColor = .green
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4)
                        {
                            borderColor = Color.black
                        }

                    }else{
                        borderColor = .red
                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.4)
                            {
                                borderColor = Color.black
                            }    
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}


I have tried to substitute Color.black for a UIColor
Originally the script had a ternary operator in the borderColor configuration inside the custom buttonStyle struct.
The error has not changed with any of these changes. I assume I’m not passing in the right value into the custom struct. I’m just at a loss for what I should be doing.

try using: .buttonStyle(..., borderColor: $borderColor)). CustomButtonStyle expects a binding, so you need to pass a binding to it using $

Be careful on what you try to achieve : if you change borderColor with your tapGesture you will change it for all buttons which may not be what you want.

Unrelated but newLetter is supposed to be let newLetter : String because it's never being modified. By the way the button style is the wrong place for the tap gesture. And actually it's not needed at all because the configuration provides an isPressed state which can be used to change the color.

Thanks for the feedback. I will make the changes you’re suggesting. Pitt Xav, you are correct that it does change all the borders colours. This is my next challenge, as I only want to change specific buttons borders colours. I’m not sure if I’m taking the right approach to achieve that. I basically want the interface to indicate to the user which button was correctly/incorrectly pressed when a button is tapped.
